# JavaFX: compatibility issue between Java 7.4 and Java 8

Tags: checkbox, javafx, treeview, tableview

I have an app that makes significant use of checkboxes in JavaFX TreeView and TableView. There is custom code as much of it was done before the enhancements that came later in JavaFX 2.2.

I now find that checkboxes that used to work do not work (as if they are disabled) although some work intermittently.

I have checked through the Oracle compatibility documentation and I can find nothing relevant.

I have a small sample app that works perfectly in Java 7.4 but shows the same faulty behaviour as the main app in Java 8.

Could anyone you please suggest where I might start looking from your own experience - e.g. cell factory, callback etc - or indicate if anything fundamental changed with this kind of construct at Java 8? I have posted the sample app code below (four separate classes).

Thank you in advance.

```
package samplefx2_original_v7;  

import javafx.application.Application;  
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;  
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;  
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;  
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;  
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.geometry.Insets;  
import javafx.scene.Group;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.control.Label;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;  
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;  
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;  
import javafx.scene.text.Font;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
import javafx.util.Callback;  

public class SampleFX2_Original_V7 extends Application {  

private TableView table = new TableView();  
private boolean everything = false;  

//Sample data for the table.  
private final ObservableList<Person> data =  
   FXCollections.observableArrayList(  
   new ControlPerson(false, "Select Columns", false, false),  
   new Person(true, "Jacob Smith", true, false),  
   new Person(true, "Isabella Johnson", true, true),  
   new Person(true, "Ethan Williams", false, false),  
   new Person(true, "Emma Jones", false, true),  
   new Person(false, "Michael Brown", true, true));  

/** 
 * @param args the command line arguments 
 */  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
 launch(args);  
}  

@Override  
public void start(Stage stage) {  
 Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());  
 stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");  
 stage.setWidth(850);  
 stage.setHeight(500);  

 final Label label = new Label("Address Book");  
 label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));  

 //A custom cell factory that creates checkboxes for a boolean property.  

 Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> colCheckFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {  

   @Override  
   public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {  
return new CheckBoxCell();  
   }  
 };  

 //The various columns  
 TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");  
 nameCol.setMinWidth(100);  
 nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));  

 TableColumn contactCol = createContactColumn(colCheckFactory);  
 TableColumn emailCol = createEmailColumn(colCheckFactory);  
 TableColumn phoneCol = createPhoneColumn(colCheckFactory);  

 //Add the columns and data to the table.  
 table.setItems(data);  
 table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, contactCol, emailCol, phoneCol);  

 //Make the table editable  
 table.setEditable(true);  
   table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);  

 final VBox vbox = new VBox();  
 vbox.setSpacing(5);  
 vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);  
 vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));  

 ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);  

 stage.setScene(scene);  
 stage.show();  
}  

private TableColumn createEmailColumn(Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory) {  
 TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");  
 emailCol.setMinWidth(75);  
 emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));  
 emailCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);  
 emailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean>>() {  

   @Override  
   public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean> event) {  
if (event.getRowValue() instanceof ControlPerson) {  
  for (Person p : data) {  
    p.setEmail(event.getNewValue());  
  }  
} else {  
  //Need to handle the indivdual cells as well as the special control cells.  
  Person p = event.getRowValue();  
  p.setEmail( event.getNewValue() );  
}  
   }  
 });  

 return emailCol;  
}  

private TableColumn createPhoneColumn(Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory) {  
 TableColumn phoneCol = new TableColumn("Phone");  
 phoneCol.setMinWidth(75);  
 phoneCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory("phone"));  
 phoneCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);  
 phoneCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean>>() {  

   @Override  
   public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean> event) {  
if (event.getRowValue() instanceof ControlPerson) {  
  for (Person p : data) {  
    p.setPhone(event.getNewValue());  
  }  
} else {  
  Person p = event.getRowValue();  
  p.setPhone( event.getNewValue() );  
}  
   }  
 });  

 return phoneCol;  
}  

/** 
 * This is the main control column in your application (containing the green and red circles). 
 * 
 * @param cellFactory 
 * @return 
 */  
private TableColumn createContactColumn( Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory ) {  
 TableColumn contactCol = new TableColumn("Contact");  
 contactCol.setMinWidth(75);  
 contactCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory( "contact"));  
 contactCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);  
 contactCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean>>() {  

   @Override  
   public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean> event) {  
//This handler is different to the other two as it controls the checking/unchecking of both  
//the whole table and individual rows.  
if (event.getRowValue() instanceof ControlPerson) {  
  for (Person p : data) {  
    p.setContact(event.getNewValue());  
    p.setEmail(event.getNewValue());  
    p.setPhone(event.getNewValue());  
  }  

  //This is just an example of how you would control a special "everything" flag.  
  //You could call any method or take any action here to deal with the special  
  //case where everything is selected.  
  everything = event.getNewValue();  
} else {  
  //Set the state of any boolean properties to modify the whole row.  
  Person p = event.getRowValue();  
  p.setContact( event.getNewValue() );  
  p.setEmail(event.getNewValue());  
  p.setPhone(event.getNewValue());  
}  
   }  
 });  

 return contactCol;  
}  
}  


package samplefx2_original_v7;  
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;  
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;  
public class Person {  

private final SimpleBooleanProperty contact;  
private final SimpleStringProperty name;  
private final SimpleBooleanProperty email;  
private final SimpleBooleanProperty phone;  

public Person(boolean contact, String name, boolean email, boolean phone) {  
 this.contact = new SimpleBooleanProperty( contact );  
 this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);  
 this.email = new SimpleBooleanProperty( email );  
 this.phone = new SimpleBooleanProperty( phone );  
}  

public String getName() {  
 return name.get();  
}  

public void setName(String name) {  
 this.name.set(name);  
}  

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {  
 return name;  
}  

public boolean isContact() {  
 return contact.get();  
}  

public void setContact( boolean contact ) {  
 this.contact.set( contact );  
}  

public SimpleBooleanProperty contactProperty() {  
 return contact;  
}  

public boolean isEmail() {  
 return email.get();  
}  

public void setEmail( boolean email ) {  
 this.email.set( email );  
}  

public SimpleBooleanProperty emailProperty() {  
 return email;  
}  

public boolean isPhone() {  
 return contact.get();  
}  

public void setPhone( boolean phone ) {  
 this.phone.set( phone );  
}  

public SimpleBooleanProperty phoneProperty() {  
 return phone;  
}  
}  


package samplefx2_original_v7;  

/** 
 * This subclass of Person is used only to identify the row(s) that is used to control 
 * the checking and unchecking of columns. 
 */  
public class ControlPerson extends Person {  

public ControlPerson(boolean active, String name, boolean email, boolean phone) {  
 super(active, name, email, phone);  
}  
}  


package samplefx2_original_v7;  

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;  
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.geometry.Pos;  
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;  
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;  


public class CheckBoxCell extends TableCell<Person, Boolean> {  

private CheckBox checkBox;  

public CheckBoxCell() {  
 if (checkBox == null) {  
   checkBox = new CheckBox();  
   checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {  

@Override  
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {  
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) event.getSource();  
  getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn());  
  commitEdit(cb.isSelected());  
}  
   });  
 }  
 setGraphic(checkBox);  
 setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);  
 //Center align the checkboxes.  
 setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);  
}  

@Override  
public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {  
 super.updateItem(item, empty);  
 if (item == null) {  
   //If we don't have an item don't draw the checkbox.  
   setGraphic( null );  
// checkBox.setDisable(true);  
// checkBox.setSelected(false);  
 } else {  
   checkBox.setDisable(false);  
   checkBox.setSelected(item);  
 }  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are going on here. A simple thing to note is that you don't set the graphic when the cell changes from empty to non-empty. You need:

```
@Override  
public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {  
 super.updateItem(item, empty);  
 if (item == null) {  
   //If we don't have an item don't draw the checkbox.  
   setGraphic( null );  
// checkBox.setDisable(true);  
// checkBox.setSelected(false);  
 } else {  
   checkBox.setDisable(false);  
   checkBox.setSelected(item);  
   setGraphic(checkBox);
 }  
}
```

But probably more of an issue is that your table cell implementation really relies on undocumented behavior, in that it forces the table into editing mode (`getTableView().edit(...)`) and (as far as I can tell) seems to rely on some side effects of this in order to get the functionality you want. Because the behavior is undocumented, there's no guarantee it will remain the same in new releases, so I'm not too surprised it breaks under Java 8.

A better way to implement the cells is just to use listeners (or bindings) to exchange data between the check box's `selectedProperty` and the property in the `Person` class. Because the display is always the same (i.e. a check box) no matter whether the cell is being edited or not, there's no really need to work with the editing API from the cell class. This is the approach the standard `CheckBoxTableCell` introduced in JavaFX 2.2 works.

Assuming the functionality you want is that the "contact" column check boxes should select both the "email" and "phone" checkboxes, I would approach this slightly differently. There's really no logical need to have a contact property in the model class (`Person`), because that information is already incorporated in the other two boolean properties. (Another way to think of this is that the "control" checkboxes are just UI components and not really part of the data, so they have no place in the model.) Your "contact" column doesn't really have a property associated with it; just make that a `TableColumn<Person, Person>` and have its cells update the other properties appropriately.

Also, your `ControlPerson` is a bit of a hack. Again this row in the table is really just for user interface purposes and is not part of the data. So it really shouldn't appear as part of the table's `items`. I would put the "select all" check boxes in the table header, not in the data part of the table. This will change their appearance some (though you can always fix that with CSS if you need) but the benefit is that they remain visible when you scroll, which is probably desirable.

Here's a complete example which works this way, and runs under both Java 7 (JavaFX 2.2) and under Java 8. (I tested under 1.7.0_65, 1.8.0_25, and 1.8.0_40.)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SampleFX2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                   new Callback<Person, Observable[]>() {
                       @Override
                       public Observable[] call(Person person) {
                           return new Observable[] {person.emailProperty(), person.phoneProperty()};
                       }
                   }); 

        data.addAll(Arrays.asList(  
                   new Person("Jacob Smith", true, false),  
                   new Person("Isabella Johnson", true, true),  
                   new Person("Ethan Williams", false, false),  
                   new Person("Emma Jones", false, true),  
                   new Person("Michael Brown", true, true)));

        final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(data);


        TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

        final CheckBox allContactCheckBox = new CheckBox() ;
        final CheckBox allEmailCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        final CheckBox allPhoneCheckBox = new CheckBox();

        updateHeaderCheckBoxes(table, allContactCheckBox, allEmailCheckBox, allPhoneCheckBox);


        data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Person> change) {
                updateHeaderCheckBoxes(table, allContactCheckBox, allEmailCheckBox, allPhoneCheckBox);
            }

        });

        allPhoneCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                    Boolean wasSelected, Boolean isSelected) {
                for (Person person : table.getItems()) {
                    person.setPhone(isSelected);
                }
            }
        });

        allEmailCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                    Boolean wasSelected, Boolean isSelected) {
                for (Person person : table.getItems()) {
                    person.setEmail(isSelected);
                }
            }
        });

        allContactCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                    Boolean wasSelected, Boolean isSelected) {
                for (Person person : table.getItems()) {
                    person.setPhone(isSelected);
                    person.setEmail(isSelected);
                }
            }
        });


        TableColumn<Person, Person> contactCol = new TableColumn<>();
        contactCol.setPrefWidth(75);
        contactCol.setGraphic(createTableHeader("Contact", allContactCheckBox));
        contactCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, Person>, ObservableValue<Person>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Person> call(
                    CellDataFeatures<Person, Person> person) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(person.getValue());
            }

        });

        contactCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Person>, TableCell<Person, Person>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Person> call(
                    TableColumn<Person, Person> param) {
                return new ContactCell();
            }

        });

        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> emailCol = new TableColumn<>();
        emailCol.setPrefWidth(75);
        emailCol.setGraphic(createTableHeader("Email", allEmailCheckBox));
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Boolean>("email"));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(
                    TableColumn<Person, Boolean> column) {
                return new CheckBoxCell<Person>(new Callback<Person, BooleanProperty>() {

                    @Override
                    public BooleanProperty call(Person person) {
                        return person.emailProperty();
                    }

                });
            }

        });

        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> phoneCol = new TableColumn<>();
        phoneCol.setPrefWidth(75);
        phoneCol.setGraphic(createTableHeader("Phone", allPhoneCheckBox));      
        phoneCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Boolean>("phone"));
        phoneCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(
                    TableColumn<Person, Boolean> column) {
                return new CheckBoxCell<Person>(new Callback<Person, BooleanProperty>() {

                    @Override
                    public BooleanProperty call(Person person) {
                        return person.phoneProperty();
                    }

                });
            }

        });


        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(contactCol);
        table.getColumns().add(emailCol);
        table.getColumns().add(phoneCol);

        Button showButton = new Button("Debug");
        showButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
                for (Person p : table.getItems()) {
                    System.out.println(p.getName() + " " + p.isEmail() +" "+ p.isPhone());
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        });


        HBox controls = new HBox(5);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.getChildren().add(showButton);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);
        root.setBottom(controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createTableHeader(String text, CheckBox checkBox) {
        VBox header = new VBox(2);
        header.setPadding(new Insets(2));
        header.getChildren().addAll(new Label(text), checkBox);
        header.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return header ;
    }

    private static void updateHeaderCheckBoxes(final TableView<Person> table,
            final CheckBox allContactCheckBox, final CheckBox allEmailCheckBox,
            final CheckBox allPhoneCheckBox) {
        boolean allPhoneSelected = true ;
        boolean noPhoneSelected = true ;
        boolean allEmailSelected = true ;
        boolean noEmailSelected = true ;
        for (Person person : table.getItems()) {
            if (person.isEmail()) {
                noEmailSelected = false ;
            } else {
                allEmailSelected = false ;
            }
            if (person.isPhone()) {
                noPhoneSelected = false ;
            } else {
                allPhoneSelected = false ;
            }
        }
        setCheckBoxState(allPhoneSelected, noPhoneSelected, allPhoneCheckBox);
        setCheckBoxState(allEmailSelected, noEmailSelected, allEmailCheckBox);
        setCheckBoxState(allPhoneSelected && allEmailSelected, noPhoneSelected && noEmailSelected, allContactCheckBox);
    }

    private static void setCheckBoxState(boolean on, boolean off, CheckBox checkBox) {
        if (on) {
            checkBox.setIndeterminate(false);
            checkBox.setSelected(true);
        } else if (off) {
            checkBox.setIndeterminate(false);
            checkBox.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            checkBox.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public static class ContactCell extends TableCell<Person, Person> {

        private final CheckBox checkBox ;

        public ContactCell() {
            checkBox = new CheckBox();

            final ChangeListener<Boolean> propertyListener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    updateCheckBox();
                }

            };

            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    Person person = getItem();
                    person.setEmail(newValue);
                    person.setPhone(newValue);
                }

            });

            itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Person>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Person> observable,
                        Person oldValue, Person newValue) {
                    if (oldValue != null) {
                        oldValue.emailProperty().removeListener(propertyListener);
                        oldValue.phoneProperty().removeListener(propertyListener);
                    }
                    if (newValue != null) {
                        newValue.emailProperty().addListener(propertyListener);
                        newValue.phoneProperty().addListener(propertyListener);
                        updateCheckBox();
                    }
                }

            });

            emptyProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                        Boolean wasEmpty, Boolean isEmpty) {
                    if (isEmpty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(checkBox);
                    }
                }

            });

            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }

        private void updateCheckBox() {
            Person person = getItem();
            if (person != null) {
                setCheckBoxState(person.isEmail() && person.isPhone(), ! person.isEmail() && ! person.isPhone(), checkBox);
                if (person.isEmail() && person.isPhone()) {
                    checkBox.setSelected(true);
                } else if (! person.isEmail() && ! person.isPhone()) {
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setIndeterminate(true);
                }
                checkBox.setIndeterminate(person.isEmail() != person.isPhone());
            }
        }

    }

    public static class CheckBoxCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Boolean> {
        private final CheckBox checkBox ;

        public CheckBoxCell(final Callback<T, BooleanProperty> propertyMapper) {
            checkBox = new CheckBox();

            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // for some reason getTableRow() returns a raw type...
                    TableRow<T> row = getTableRow();
                    if (row != null) {
                        T item = row.getItem();
                        if (item != null) {
                            BooleanProperty property = propertyMapper.call(item);
                            property.set(newValue);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (newValue != null) {
                    checkBox.setSelected(newValue);
                    }
                }

            });

            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            emptyProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(checkBox);
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    }

    public static class Person {  

        private final StringProperty name;  
        private final BooleanProperty email;  
        private final BooleanProperty phone;  

        public Person(String name, boolean email, boolean phone) {  
         this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);  
         this.email = new SimpleBooleanProperty( email );  
         this.phone = new SimpleBooleanProperty( phone );  
        }  

        public String getName() {  
         return name.get();  
        }  

        public void setName(String name) {  
         this.name.set(name);  
        }  

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {  
         return name;  
        }  

        public boolean isEmail() {  
         return email.get();  
        }  

        public void setEmail( boolean email ) {  
         this.email.set( email );  
        }  

        public BooleanProperty emailProperty() {  
         return email;  
        }  

        public boolean isPhone() {  
         return phone.get();  
        }  

        public void setPhone( boolean phone ) {  
         this.phone.set( phone );  
        }  

        public BooleanProperty phoneProperty() {  
         return phone;  
        }  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion but making that change does not change the way that the program behaves. It still works as previously with Java 7.4 but shows the same problem with Java 8.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't (only just now had the chance to test it). Your cell factories should always handle cases of transitioning in and out of the empty state anyway. If I get a chance I will play around with this and see if I can figure it out. You have a bit of a hack in there as you force the cell into editing mode just to get a commit edit, and I guess the implementation changed and messed that up. I would probably implement all this in the model anyway.

Comment: It will be great if you can figure out what is happening. I think this code would have been done differently if we had had the JavaFX 2.2 enhancements at the time it was done. It reassures me that you think that the underlying implementation changed.  Crossing my fingers that you can figure it out. Many thanks, David

Comment: See updated answer. (As an aside, it's ages since I worked with Java 7; the code seems so verbose now. This would be much, much more concise in Java 8.)

Comment: James, thank you so much for a comprehensive answer, tutorial and rework of my test program. It is gone midnight here so I am going to leave it until the morning to run it myself and figure out the implications for code changes in the main application itself. I know Java 8 can be more concise but I sometimes wonder if that comes at the expense of loss of transparency. More tomorrow .. your reply is truly outstanding.

Comment: FWIW, I rewrote the example using a Java 8 coding style. It reduced the code from 448 lines to 287 lines; the only things that were removed were the boilerplate from anonymous inner classes and a couple of explicit loops (which were replaced by calls to `forEach`). I find the Java 8 code much more readable as it reduces it just to the pertinent calls (though to be fair I've been using Java 8 for well over a year now).

Comment: Thank you again, James. I have tried your revised example with Java 7 and Java 8 and it behaves as expected, However, taking the whole concept forward as-is into the original application would be something of a challenge. There I have hundreds of different tables generated on-the-fly from xml, (comment continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) Each of the tables may have up to approximately 50 columns and multi-line column headings (where a a hierarchy of headings may span sets of columns) are a regular feature.  Adding the checkbox graphic to the final headings row would obviously be possible but I would undoubtedly find myself clearing up the logic debris elsewhere after that! That said, I am looking forward to moving to Java 8 and, once again, I would like to say how much I appreciate the time you have spent on this issue for me. Hopefully other users of stackoverflow will also benefit.